# Template column inside DetailView in Telerik Grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik, telerik-grid

My nested template column is not appearing in my markup when page loads.  I´m trying to load a grid with a template column within a DetailView of another parent-grid.  I can see my data being passed and clearly the "Name" of the UnitPeriod appears but nothing within my template column, so it seems as the data is being passed into the grid.  I´ve checked the source with firebug and that column always loads empty.  Can any1 spot why?

```
<div>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<RentableUnit>()
    .Name("RentableUnits")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.UnitID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(e => e.Name).Width(75);
    })
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("employees_onRowDataBound")
                            .OnDetailViewExpand("unit_onDetailViewExpand")
                            .OnDetailViewCollapse("unit_onDetailViewCollapse"))
    .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
        Html.Telerik().Grid<UnitPeriod>()
            .Name("UnitPeriod_<#= UnitID #>")
            .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
                    columns.Template(@<text>
                     @foreach (Day day in item.Days)
                     {
                         if (!day.IsRentable)
                         {
                             <img src="../../Content/Images/Houses/icon_lokad.png"/>
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             <img src="../../Content/Images/Houses/icon_opid.png"/>
                         }
                     }
             </text>);
            })
            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("orders_onRowDataBound"))
            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("SelectedUnitPeriod", "Home", new { unitId = "<#= UnitID #>" }))
            .ToHtmlString()
    ))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("RentableUnits", "Home"))
    .Sortable()
    )
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var derpinski = "";
    function expandFirstRow(grid, row) {
        if (grid.$rows().index(row) == 0) {
            grid.expandRow(row);
        }
    }

function loadTabGridContent(e) {
    var url = '/Home/TabGridContent/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            $('#TabGridContent').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function employees_onRowDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
    expandFirstRow(grid, e.row);
}

function orders_onRowDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
    expandFirstRow(grid, e.row);
}

function unit_onDetailViewExpand(e) {
    var mstRow = e.masterRow;
    var unitNumber = mstRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    derpinski = derpinski + unitNumber + ",";
}

function unit_onDetailViewCollapse(e) {
    var mstRow = e.masterRow;
    var unitNumber = mstRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    derpinski = derpinski.replace(unitNumber + ",", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is not possible with a nested grid.

I ended up in making a string variable in my custom class and used the Bound mechanism in the Telerik grid and encode the html-string in the grid.  It wasn´t the most pretty solution but it worked as far as I needed it to be.

Something like this:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult SelectedUnitPeriod(int unitId, string startDate)
{
    // Some stuff (just to abbreviate
    unitPeriodName = "";  // Created the row as string
    daystr = "";          // also with this one
    rentableUnitPeriods.Add(new RentableUnitPeriod(unitPeriod.UnitId, unitPeriodName, dayStr, unitPeriod.PrimaryImg));
    return View(new GridModel(rentableUnitPeriods));
}
```

This is what did the trick for me  :)